# Angular, restangular - abort search call if more current one comes in

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, restangular

I have to pull some data from a service using a restangular call. The server has recently gotten slow - so I was looking for a way to possibly abort the call (or maybe just the promise) if a newer call comes in and tell my service to use the most recent call.  Here is the service call -

```
  MySearchService.prototype.search = function(query) {

           return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
               var url = '/services/search';
               Restangular.oneUrl(url, url)
                    .customPOST(query)
                    .then(resolve)
                    .catch(reject);
           });
  };
```

I was thinking something like

```
.withHttpConfig({hasNewSearch: abort.promise}) <<not sure you can put custom key in here
abort.resolve();
```

But I don't think that's how you hook onto it. I am looking for a way to cancel the call if there is a newer call, perhaps this is entirely with the promise, and not really restangular at all? Would appreciate any advice. Thank you!

Comment: Note you have a `then(success,fail)` antipattern there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a cool problem, typically called `last` or `flatMapLatest`.

```
// we want something that takes a function and only cares about the last result
function last(fn){ // fn returns a promise
  var lastValue = null; // the last promise to check against
  return function(){ 
    // call the function, and mark it as the last call
    lastValue = fn.apply(this, arguments); 
    var p = lastValue;
    return p.then(function validateLast(v){ // call the function, when it resolves
        if(p === lastValue){ // if we're still the "last call" when we resolved
            return v; // we're done, successful call
        } else {
            // a newer one came, resolve with it and verify no one came since
            return lastValue.then(validateLast);
        }
    });
}
```

This would let you do something like

```
MySearchService.prototype.search = last(function(query) {
           // removed antipattern
           return Restangular.oneUrl('/services/search', '/services/search')
                             .customPOST(query);
});
```

Comment: I need a resolve still, where would i put it in this logics? Thanks by the way this is awesome!

Comment: @ajmajmajma what do you mean "I need resolve still"?

Comment: @ajmajmajma did you read https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-thensuccess-fail-anti-pattern

Comment: the `.then(resolve)` bit in the initial code. Sorry and still very new to this, will check that out.

Comment: I swapped p in your example for $q, not sure if that is right

Comment: @ajmajmajma if something has a `then` it already is a promise, there is no need to wrap it in another promise :)

Comment: Doing `new $q(function(resolve, reject){ promise.then(resolve).catch(reject); })` is _almost_ the same as just doing `promise`, it's mostly pointless.

Comment: This is definitely what i'm looking for, i'm just struggling with the implementation details. I will mark it as correct, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Sorry one last question - what is the `p` suppose to be?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, fixed.

Comment: and im assuming argument should be arguments? or is it representative?

Comment: Yes sorry, deploy day at work I only get to answer in compile times :D

Comment: No worries, and thank you very much again for your help. This is unbelievably helpful!

Comment: So, this is working great, however it is making all the calls, and returning the same payload, is it possible do cancel the old calls that are being overwritten entirely and just use the current most call?

Comment: @ajmajmajma yes, whenever you make a new call you can start by aborting the old one, you can do it in the line above `lastValue = fn.apply(...)` where you still have access to the "old" lastValue.

Comment: Neat solution. I would add that in natural (English) language semantics, "latest" conveys the nature of this flatmapping better than "last", which is ambiguous. "Last" can indeed mean "latest" but can also mean "one before latest" or "previous". Maybe it's just me but I only understood the function once I realised "last" to mean "latest".

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I didn't coin the terminology and I agree https://github.com/domenic/last